# Redirect URL using Query String parameter in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I have a bunch of URLs from an old site that I recently updated to EE2.  These URLs look like this:
http://www.example.com/old/path.asp?dir=Folder_Name

These URLs will need to redirect to:
http://www.example.com/new_path/folders/folder_name

Not all `Folder_Name` strings match up with `folder_name` URL segments, so these will most likely need to be static redirects.

I tried the following Rule for a particular folder called "Example_One" which maps to a page on the new site called "example1":

```
Redirect 301 /old/path.asp?dir=Example_One
             http://www.example.com/new_path/folders/example1
```

But this doesn't work. Instead of redirecting I just get a 404 error telling me that http://www.example.com/old/path.asp?dir=Example_One cannot be found.

**EDIT:**
There's a secondary problem here too which may or may not be related:  I have a catch-all rule that looks like this:
redirect 301 /old/path.asp  http://www.example.com/new_path

Using the rule, requests like the first one above will be redirected to:
http://www.example.com/new_path?dir=Folder_Namewhich triggers a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to scour Google a bit more to find the proper syntax for mod_rewrite.

Using the example from above:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dir=Example_One$
RewriteRule ^/old/path\.asp$ /new_path/folders/example1? [R=301,L]
```

This fixes both of the problems above -- as to why EE is 404ing with one parameter in the Query String, that problem is still unsolved, but this works as a workaround to that problem.

You can also redirect URLs to a specific page where the parameter may have a different value each time.  One example of this is Google UTM Campaign tracking (in situations like this where the tracking query string triggers a 404):

Link: http://www.example.com/?utm_source=xxx&.....  (triggers 404)
Should Redirect to: http://www.example.com

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com? [R=301,L]
```

Note: This will only redirect those requests to the homepage, as defined by ^$.  If you want to redirect utm requests to a different page, you'll need to change the first part of that RewriteRule.

Comment: Wouldn't ^dir=Example_One$ not work if there were any other query string parameters (e.g. http://www.example.com/old/path.asp?dir=Example_One&a=b)?